# How to remove a header and footer from a Google Drive document?

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to remove a header and footer from a Google Drive document?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the Google Documents UI doesn't include a menu to remove the header/footer but this could be done by using Google Apps Script.

Example

The following script removes de document header

```
function removeHeader() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  doc.getHeader().removeFromParent();
}
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs